# Makefile failing to match all target files in the src directory

Tags: makefile

In an effort to learn about `make`, I'm inspecting the following Makefile, generated by the `configure` script in an older version of [an open-source project](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/blob/c4395e58201966d9f90c12bd6b7342e389e7a4cb/src/Makefile.in):

```
CC = gcc

CFLAGS = 
LOCAL_CFLAGS = 
DEFS = 
LOCAL_DEFS = 

CCFLAGS = $(DEFS) $(LOCAL_DEFS) $(LOCAL_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)

SHOBJ_CC = gcc
SHOBJ_CFLAGS = -fno-common
SHOBJ_LD = ${CC}
SHOBJ_LDFLAGS = -dynamiclib -dynamic -undefined dynamic_lookup 
SHOBJ_XLDFLAGS = 
SHOBJ_LIBS = 
SHOBJ_STATUS = supported

.c.o:
    $(SHOBJ_CC) $(SHOBJ_CFLAGS) $(CCFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

../libexec/rbenv-realpath.dylib: realpath.o
    $(SHOBJ_LD) $(SHOBJ_LDFLAGS) $(SHOBJ_XLDFLAGS) -o $@ realpath.o $(SHOBJ_LIBS)

clean:
    rm -f *.o ../libexec/*.dylib
```

I'm using this Makefile to learn how `make` works.  One of the first things I've learned so far is that the syntax `.c.o:` corresponds to an [old-fashioned suffix rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Suffix-Rules).

I know that this open-source project kept the old-fashioned syntax in place for backwards-compatibility reasons, and I know that the preferred newer syntax is to use pattern rules.
Nevertheless, I wanted to solidify my understanding of this syntax, and make sure it works the way I expected it to.

I read the following in the GCC docs linked above:

> A double-suffix rule is defined by a pair of suffixes: the target suffix and the source suffix. It matches any file whose name ends with the target suffix. The corresponding implicit prerequisite is made by replacing the target suffix with the source suffix in the file name. A two-suffix rule ‘.c.o’ (whose target and source suffixes are ‘.o’ and ‘.c’) is equivalent to the pattern rule ‘%.o : %.c’.

Therefore, my expectation is that this suffix rule would watch for changes in files using the ".c" file extension inside the same directory as the Makefile, and would create a target file with the same filename but with the ".o" file extension instead.  I already see one ".c" file in the directory, named "realpath.c":

```
~/Workspace/OpenSource/rbenv/src (remotes/origin/HEAD~23)  $ ls

Makefile.in bash.h      configure   realpath.c  shobj-conf
```

As a sanity check, I run the `configure` script and then run `make` using the generated Makefile.  I see the following output:

```
~/Workspace/OpenSource/rbenv/src (remotes/origin/HEAD~23)  $ ./configure

~/Workspace/OpenSource/rbenv/src (remotes/origin/HEAD~23)  $ ls

Makefile    Makefile.in bash.h      configure   realpath.c  shobj-conf

~/Workspace/OpenSource/rbenv/src (remotes/origin/HEAD~23)  $ make

gcc -fno-common     -c -o realpath.o realpath.c
gcc -dynamiclib -dynamic -undefined dynamic_lookup   -o ../libexec/rbenv-realpath.dylib realpath.o
```

So far, so good.  Everything happens as expected.

Now, I add a new file to the directory named `foo.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
 printf("Hello world!");
}
```

My hypothesis was that, if ".c.o matches any file whose name ends with the target suffix", and if "(t)he corresponding implicit prerequisite is made by replacing the target suffix with the source suffix in the file name" (both of which are stated in the docs), then any and all ".c" files in the target directory would be used to generate a corresponding ".o" file.  By removing the the previously-generated "realpath.o" file, I would expect a re-run of `make` to create not one but *two* ".o" files- one called "realpath.o" and one called "foo.o".  Additionally, I should see a separate `gcc -fno-common     -c -o` logline for each target-source combination, i.e.:

```
gcc -fno-common     -c -o realpath.o realpath.c
gcc -fno-common     -c -o foo.o foo.c
...
```

I remove the previously-generated files and re-run `make`, but the effects I observe do not match my expectations.  Instead, I continue to see only one ".o" file generated and one logline for `realpath.o realpath.c`, with no logline for `foo.c`:

```
~/Workspace/OpenSource/rbenv/src (remotes/origin/HEAD~23)  $ ls

Makefile.in bash.h      configure   foo.c       realpath.c  shobj-conf

~/Workspace/OpenSource/rbenv/src (remotes/origin/HEAD~23)  $ ./configure

~/Workspace/OpenSource/rbenv/src (remotes/origin/HEAD~23)  $ make

gcc -fno-common     -c -o realpath.o realpath.c
gcc -dynamiclib -dynamic -undefined dynamic_lookup   -o ../libexec/rbenv-realpath.dylib realpath.o

~/Workspace/OpenSource/rbenv/src (remotes/origin/HEAD~23)  $ ls

Makefile    Makefile.in bash.h      configure   foo.c       realpath.c  realpath.o  shobj-conf
```

I know the subsequent rule with the ".dylib" target file does indeed specify "realpath.o" as a dependency, but that rule runs downstream of the suffix rule, and that 2nd rule's generated output doesn't include any object files, so I believe it's unrelated to my question.  I see nothing in [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Suffix-Rules) which leads me to believe that my new `foo.c` file would be excluded, given the contents of my `Makefile`.

Where am I going wrong in my expectation?

Comment: *I know that the preferred newer syntax is to use pattern rules* -- you know wrong.  Pattern rules are a feature specific to GNU's version of `make`, which is very popular, but is by no means the only `make`.  The GNU Make documentation does push pattern rules pretty hard, but that's not an older / newer thing, it's a GNU-says-it's-superior thing that's relevant only if you are committed specifically to GNU `make`.  If you want compatibility with versions of `make` other than GNU's then pattern rules are right out.

Comment: Just to be fair, while it's true that suffix rules are not deprecated (they are required by POSIX and not going anywhere), there are many things that are simply impossible to do with suffix rules.  The reason that GNU make pushes pattern rules is because they're (a) easier to understand and (b) much more powerful than suffix rules.  But, if you don't need anything fancier than suffix rules it's fine to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my expectation is that this suffix rule would watch for changes in files using the ".c" file extension inside the same directory as the Makefile, and would create a target file with the same filename but with the ".o" file extension instead.

No, that's pretty much exactly backwards.  `make` rules describe how to build certain *targets* specified in the makefile, in service ultimately to building one or more goal targets that are either specified explicitly or chosen by default.  The concept is more or less "X depends on Y and Z, and if you need to build X then here's how".  The *if you need to build X* part is key.  `make` does not automatically build targets just because it has a rule by which it could do so.

In a `.c.o` rule, the target suffix is `.o`, not `.c`.  The rule matches any targets that need to be built whose names end with `.o`, which has nothing in particular to do with what files are present.  Nor with directories -- such a rule would match a target named `sub/dir/target1.o` as much as it would match one named `target2.o`.

However, the rule *applies* to building such a target only if there is a corresponding `.c` file, whether `sub/dir/target1.c` or `target2.c`.  It will not be used to build targets to which it does not apply.  Of the pair, the `.o` file is the rule's target, and the `.c` file is its prerequisite.  If that suffix rule is chosen for a given `.o` file, then the relative modification timestamps of that file and the corresponding `.c` file will be used to determine whether the existing `.o`, if any, needs to be rebuilt.

So,

> My hypothesis was that, if ".c.o matches any file whose name ends with
> the target suffix",

Mostly yes.  `.c.o` matches any *target* whose name ends with the target suffix.  Which, incidentally, is `.o`.

> and if "(t)he corresponding implicit prerequisite
> is made by replacing the target suffix with the source suffix in the
> file name" (both of which are stated in the docs),

Yes.  With the source suffix in this case being `.c`.

> then any and all
> ".c" files in the target directory would be used to generate a
> corresponding ".o" file.

No, not at all.  Again, in addition to the mixup of source and target suffixes, `make` builds only those targets it is *asked* to build (the goal targets), plus those additional targets it *needs* to build as direct or indirect prerequisites for building the goal targets.

Comment: Some people seem to interpret a implicit rule (suffix or pattern rule) to tell make, "go find all the possible targets that could be built based on the implicit rule and build them"; they sort of think of it like `ls *.c` which lists all the `.c` files.  But that's not at all what they are: implicit rules are _templates_ that make can use to build a target that matches the template, _if_ make needs to build it and you didn't tell it any other way (an explicit rule) to build it.

Comment: @MadScientist this was exactly my thought process.  Your comment clarified what was happening here; my current understanding is that `make` will only build a target file *if it needs to do so*, and it determines whether it needs to do so by whether that target file is listed as a dependency for a subsequent rule.  I added `foo.o` as a prerequisite of the 2nd rule in my `Makefile` and re-ran `make`, and I saw that `foo.o` was in fact generated this time around.  Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @JohnBollinger it sounds like you thought I was confused about whether ".c" files were targets and ".o" files were prerequisites.  In fact, I did already know that the reverse was true.  It seems I simply didn't communicate my understanding  sufficiently in my question.  Thanks for the feedback.

That said, your answer does indeed address the root of my misunderstanding.  I had thought that `make` will not automatically look for any and all ".c" files and turn them into ".o" files just because they are present in a given directory.  Now I know better.  Thanks for the assistance!